# Laravel 5.8: Google map API auto complete errors

Tags: google-maps, laravel-5, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, geolocation

I am using geolocation in my laravel 5.8 project.

I want to use google map API auto complete in the search box. I created my own API key, and pasted link but it doesn't work.

I tried 3 links. First one is:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

And then the error is the below.

> This API project is not authorized to use this API.

Secondly, I tried this code:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"
```

> Uncaught (in promise). initMap is not a function

Lastly, I put this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1600+Amphitheatre&key=KEY&sessiontoken=1234567890" async defer></script>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

and error point is here: **footer.blade.php**

[image: error code]

Comment: **This API project is not authorized to use this API**. There even is a link in the error message.

Comment: Please don't post pictures (only) of code/error messages, they are not searchable, post the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not enabled the **Places API** on your project. Follow the steps in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/enable-disable-apis#enable_an_api) to enable it. Make sure that the JavaScript API is also enabled.

Also, you cannot call the Places API web service in **client-side** JavaScript. Web services are **server-side**. To understand the difference between [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) (web service) and the [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) (JS API client-side service) please refer to Google's documentation.

To implement Autocomplete you can use [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) for guidance.

Hope this helps!